# Go module import from github

Tags: go, module

I am new to golang and trying to import and use modules from this Github repo. https://github.com/Darkbladecr/ccxt/tree/go/go

I am using go module to manage dependencies but importing is failed.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/Darkbladecr/ccxt/go/pkg/ccxt/models"
)
```

But I got this error.

```
go: finding github.com/Darkbladecr/ccxt latest
build command-line-arguments: cannot load github.com/Darkbladecr/ccxt/go/pkg/ccxt/models: cannot find module providing package github.com/Darkbladecr/ccxt/go/pkg/ccxt/models
```

Is it possible to import a specific directory for go like this repo?

Comment: Does that directory exist in that project on github? As far as I can tell, it doesn't.

Comment: I think it does. The root directory is https://github.com/Darkbladecr/ccxt/tree/go.

Comment: It is not on the master branch, it is on the "go" branch. IIRC, go get github.com/Darkbladecr/ccxtl@go should get you that branch (I think).

Comment: Oh, yes. Sorry, I did not see it. It worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can either `go get` the branch containing that package explicitly, or add explicit version tags on that branch in the format that the `go` tool recognizes (with a leading `v` prefix on the tags, such as `v1.18.445` or `v0.1.0-go`).